# Fibonacci sequence value in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation

how to get sum of fibonacci sequence using that code:

```
fibs= 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

edit: take 5 fibs gives list of [0,1,1,2,3], so the value of 5th element is 3, to extract it we have to type : 'last(take(5 fibs))' and we get 3. And so on

if we use interpreter to seek for 5th element we get list of [ 0, 1, 2, 3] the last element is the same what value of 5th element, how to get LAST element of that list?
Can I 'make' it using `last` , do you have any ideas, could you?

Comment: let fiblist = 0:1 : (zipWith (+) fiblist (tail fiblist)) in (last(take 5 fiblist))

this is what (I think) that solves my problem
For example for fiblist 5 i get 3 , for 15 -> 377 so the correct value of Fibonacci's element 
Well it works but isnt pretty;)

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly identify what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, but if you have a non-empty non-infinite (i.e., not `fibs` but, for example, `take n fibs` for some `n`) list, you can indeed obtain its last element by applying `last` to it.  Alternatively, if you just want the n-th element of a list (starting at zero and assuming the list has at least n+1 elements), you can do `listName !! n` to extract it.

Answer (score 5):

That definition yields an **infinite** stream of integers. There is no last element.

If instead you want to index a particular element from the list, you can do so with the `(!!)` operator:

```
> [1..] !! 7
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want the 10th element of the list:

```
last (take 10 fibs)
```

if you want the sum of the first 10 elements:

```
sum (take 10 fibs)
```

BTW there is a slightly simpler expression for fibs, using just recursion:

```
fibs = (fibgen 0 1) where fibgen a b = a : fibgen b (a+b)
```